# CSS div border changes to black when visited

Tags: css

I have a menu where each link is a **div** box. This div box have a gray border-bottom, however, when the link is visited it turns black. I just can't figure why.

On the following image I've clicked the *Rediger profil* and *Log af* links.

[image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LpGbT/

**HTML**

```
        <div id="design_sidebar">
            <div id="design_sidebar_head">
                Patrick Reck
            </div>

            <a href="#"><div class="design_sidebar_menu_item">Besøgende</div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="design_sidebar_menu_item">Mine favoritter</div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('profile/editProfile');?>"><div class="design_sidebar_menu_item">Rediger profil</div></a>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('user/logout');?>"><div class="design_sidebar_menu_item">Log af</div></a>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#design_sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;

    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

    background-color: white;
}

#design_sidebar_head {
    width: 165px;
    height: 30px;

    font-family: Segoe; 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;

    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;

    background-image: url('../img/icons/user.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 11px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.design_sidebar_menu_item {

    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;

    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.design_sidebar_menu_item:hover {
    color: white;

    background-color: #a6242f;
}
```

Comment: are you using any kind of framework like bootstrap for example that has its own styles?

Comment: The only framework I am using is CodeIgniter. No styles there

Comment: cant replicate it in your jsfiddle? so unsure what the problem is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it doesn't harm your design etc. I would suggest this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="design_sidebar">
<div id="design_sidebar_head">
Patrick Reck
</div>
<a href="#">Patrick Reck</a>
<a href="#">Besøgende</a>
<a href="#">Mine favoritter</a> 
<a href="<?php echo site_url('profile/editProfile');?>">Rediger profil</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/logout');?>">Log af</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#design_sidebar a {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
display: block;
}

div#design_sidebar a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: #a6242f;
}

#design_sidebar {
width: 200px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: white;
}

#design_sidebar_head {
width: 165px;
height: 30px;
font-family: Segoe;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #333333;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 35px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
background-image: url('../img/icons/user.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px 11px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

EDIT:

How about adding:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

And removing `border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;` from `.design_sidebar_menu_item {...}`
The others will need links around them for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I'm afraid that will mess up the intended design

Comment: No problem, i have just edited my answer above, this may be what you are after.

Comment: these kinds of answers would be much more helpful if you provided an explanation of what you did and how it solved the problem.. code shouldn't be black magic and the lesson should be summarized, rather then looking through the code..

Answer (score 0):

You may define a copied version of your div selector with a `:visited` suffix in order to set new colours for visited objects.

Aldo div classes are prefixed with a dot (`.`) instead of a sharp (`#`) character. Just a reminder. :)

```
.design_sidebar_menu_item:visited {
  border-color: <your_color>;
}
```

Comment: My prefixes are right. Classes are prefixed with `.` and IDs are prefixed with `#`.

Unfortunately I've already tried using `:visited` and it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't..
I changed border-bottom color to 'green'. Now you have a clear view.

Check jsFiddle :  [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/LpGbT/13/)

```
.design_sidebar_menu_item {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00FF00;
}
```